# From a net core class library I can reference a net framework class library, but vice versa I cannot

Tags: asp.net-core

From a "net core class library (targets .net core 2.0)" I **can** add a reference to a "net framework class library (targets .net framework 4.5.1)" but vice versa I **cannot** (compile error). Why?

All established under a single solution, all references assigned as Project references.

VS 2017 15.5.1.

Thanks.

**OK**

[image: ok.png]

**Compile Error**

[image: compile error.png]

Comment: If you want to use a .NET Core library in .NET Framework, then you'll need to build the .NET Core library as a .NET Standard one. I would take a look at the following resources to refresh or learn about .NET Standard: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt842506.aspx and https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/On-NET/Immo-Landwerth-Net-Standard

Comment: Perfect link, thanks.

Comment: No worries. I'm glad that I could help.